# How do you set a cooldown on a Slash command?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I recently started working on Discord JS v13 with Slash commands and I was wondering, how can I set cooldowns to the commands? And if it's possible, could you please show me an example?

This is my test code:

```
const { Permissions, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 data: new SlashCommandBuilder()   
 .setName("test")
 .setDescription("Test command."),

 async run (client, interaction, message){

 interaction.reply({ content: "What is this uwu", ephemeral: true })
 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which I used and it worked:

First you have to create a Set

```
const cooldown = new Set();
///This is 1 minute, you can change it to whatever value
const cooldownTime = 60000;
```

Then this is the code:

```
if (cooldown.has(interaction.user.id)) {
    /// If the cooldown did not end
    interaction.reply({ content: "Please wait for the cooldown to end", ephemeral: true });
    
  } else {
    /// Else give the reply
    interaction.reply({ content: "What is this uwu", ephemeral: true });

    //now, set cooldown
   cooldown.add(interaction.user.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Removes the user from the set after 1 minute
          cooldown.delete(interaction.user.id);
        }, cooldownTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, create a discord.js collection to store users' cooldown and set cooldown time.

```js
// index.js
client.cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
client.COOLDOWN_SECONDS = 10; // replace with desired cooldown time in seconds
```

When a user executes a command, check if the user exists in the cooldown. If so, notify it to the user.
If not, run the comnand and set cooldown. After the time you specified, remove it.

```js
// command file
async run(client, interaction, message) {
  if (client.cooldowns.has(interaction.user.id)) {
    // cooldown not ended
    interaction.reply({ content: "Please wait for cooldown to end", ephemeral: true });
  } else {
    // no cooldown
    // do something here

    //now, set cooldown
    client.cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, true);

    // After the time you specified, remove the cooldown
    setTimeout(() => {
      client.cooldowns.delete(interaction.user.id);
    }, client.COOLDOWN_SECONDS * 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example didn't work for me but I managed to fix it, which was basically the same thing!